# Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0 with gradle-appengine-plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2, appengine-gradle-plugin

When attempting to upgrade to Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0 using the [gradle appengine plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) I run across a conflict with the configuration `endpoints`.  Gradle reports the error:

```
Error:Cannot add a configuration with name 'endpoints' as a configuration with that name already exists.
```

Switching to the newer [appengine gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin) avoids the problem, except that it (1) doesn't support Android studio, (2) and has crappy JDO support ([upgrade doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle)).

Does anyone have a solution to use the older plugin with Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0?

Comment: Have you read this Transition process? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

Comment: In general this works. Sounds more like an issue with your Gradle config. You could post your build.gradle files. The newer plugin is still incompatible (not just unsupported, it simply doesn't work) with Android Studio for some reason, don't go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because the V2 `endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin` and the `gradle-appengine-plugin` both contain tasks named `endpoints`.  Removing the V2 plugin does not work, because the `gradle-appengine-plugin` version does not support V2 Cloud Endpoints.

In the end, I had to migrate to the new appengine gradle plugin as suggested in the [Android upgrade doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android#migrate).  This requires building and deploying from the command line and a custom task to handle JDO, but otherwise works fine.